# React Native npm run android is installing old apk in phone and looking for automated tools for generating offline apks

Tags: android, react-native, npm, automated-deploy

For some reason android is keep installing the oldest apk in mobile devices, The Js code is not updated. I tried following methods:

1. I tried using `npm run android`
2. I tried installing apk through android studio.
3. I made the release and debug apk through android studio and install it manually on devices.

None of the above method works.

Somewhere I found that first I need to Bundle script using following

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

In order to compile assets everytime for an offline apk. I believe this is not a good method ,I don't want to bundle every time after changes.

I want whole apk generation process to be automated. So Kindly guide me for tools and process for automating this whole process.

Comment: Is there an `.git/index.lock` file in your project directory?

Comment: no there is no such file in my project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue occured due to cache,Uninstall the app from device and delete the build folder inside.

```
android/app/
```

Create an Assets Folder

```
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
```

Run bundle script

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Execute command to run android to create debug apk

```
react-native run-android
```

For Automated deployment, you might take a look Fastlane.you may require other tools also.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/cross-platform/react-native/

Also read this article , it might help you also getting started with FastLane
https://carloscuesta.me/blog/shipping-react-native-apps-with-fastlane

Comment: did you bundled app again , before doing react-native run-android ,after deleting the build folder.

Comment: can you write down all the steps as answer, I will follow and see if that works. I am not sure what do you mean by bundle.

Comment: If you read my question above I wrote the bundle script there that this is not a write way to do this job, I am looking for a proper automated solution that whenever I run `npm run android` it should update the app in device automatically, otherwise this way is just a huge hurdle.

Comment: sorry about that I misunderstood, I have update my answer, you can check the link , It is good learn it, but may take you a lot of time to that, As in mobile app its a bit confusing as compared to web.

Comment: Thanks @Shahid I will look into this in detail.